# Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions. MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Na minha página inicial, tem um botão de atalho que abre um modal, e dentro desse modal tem uma *partialView* que aponta para uma *action* dentro de outro *controller*. Até aí tranquilo.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalCreate" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="createClasseModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                   @Html.Action("Create","Classes")
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Ao abrir o modal com a *partial view* sendo exibida corretamente para inclusão da informação. Após a inclusão, a rotina executa o `savechanges` corretamente no *controller*, depois ele dá um `RedirectToAction` para voltar à tela da home.

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id,descricao,dia_1,dia_2,horario,dt_inicio,dt_termino,sala,limite_max,limite_min,preco,status,professor")] Classe classe)
    {
        ViewBag.professor = new SelectList(db.Pessoa, "id", "nome", classe.professor);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Classe.Add(classe);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }

        return View(classe);
    }
```

Aí no *debug* ele volta para a `index`, e no momento de redesenhar a tela com o modal, ele acusa o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém tem alguma ideia para corrigir isso?

Comment: Correção, no controller está `return RedirectToAction("Index");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro já diz tudo. Você não pode usar uma *Action* chamada por uma *View* para redirecionar requisições. O motivo disso é evitar cascateamento de redirecionamentos.

O correto no seu caso seria a *View* principal fazer o `POST`(através da modal mesmo). A modal pode ser montada através duma *partial* em JavaScript sem necessariamente chamar uma *Action*:

```
@Html.Partial("_MinhaModal", Model)
```

Comment: Bom, se entendi, pois sou novato em c#, você está sugerindo que eu troque o Action pelo Partial na chamada da partial dentro da janela modal. É isso?

Comment: Não. Estou sugerindo que a Modal seja chamada por JavaScript, e a *Partial* seja chamada e escrita dentro de uma `<div>` oculta.

Comment: como faço essa <div> oculta?

Comment: `<div style="display:none">`.

Comment: Vai ficar complicado pois não manjo de javascript.

Comment: [Aqui tem uma boa introdução a jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-mobile/getting-started/). Resolve perfeitamente bem para o seu caso. Projetos ASP.NET MVC já vêm com jQuery instalado por padrão.

Comment: Vou pesquisar.Valeu pela ajuda

Comment: Mais complicou do que ajudou, to sem saber por onde começar lá. Alguém tem mais alguma ajuda?

Comment: @PabloRamonBorges Veja este aqui: http://jquerybrasil.org/tutoriais/. Qualquer coisa te coloco num chat com uma turma que pode te ajudar.